# Don't understand why dot notation doesn't work for composed objects

Tags: python, class, hierarchy, composition

Here is what I am trying

```
# This is how I understood composition to work
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = ''
        self.attr2 = 0
        self.attr3 = ''

    def some_update(self, newval):
        self.attr3 = newval

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr4 = ''
        self.sub1 = A()
    self.sub2 = A()
        self.sub2.attr1 = subspecialval

    def different_update(self, newval1, newval2)
        self.sub1.attr2 = newval1
        self.sub2.attr2 = newval2

def __main__():
    my_obj = B()
    B.sub1.attr = 'some string'               # This doesn't work
    setattr(B, 'sub1.attr1', 'some string')   # This works
    print(B.sub1.attr1)                       # This doesn't work
    print(getattr(B, 'sub1.attr1'))           # This works

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The questions is, why does the dot notation not extend to composed classes(B), but getattr/setattr are able to negotiate the class heirarchy correctly? I assumed that each dot would extend to the next object level in the heirarchy, but it does not seem to work that way

Answer (score 1):

> getattr/setattr are able to negotiate the class hierarchy correctly?

It is not.

`setattr(B, 'sub1.attr1', 'some string')` sets the literal attribute `'sub1.attr1'`. Nothing is being traversed or negotiated.

Keep in mind, you are setting the attribute on the class (`B`) rather than the instance (`my_obj`). `my_obj.sub1.attr` would have worked.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr2 = ''

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()


B.a.attr1 = ''

AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'a'
```

On the other hand,

```
b = B()
b.a.attr1 = 'attr1'
print(b.a.attr1)
```

Works.

---

What is `setattr(B, 'a.attr1', 'new')` doing?

It sets the literal attribute `'a.attr1` on the `B` **class** itself. Nothing is travered or netgotiated.

```
setattr(B, 'a.attr1', 'new')
print(B.__dict__)
```

Outputs

```
{'__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function B.__init__ at 0x00000188F1EB9F28>, 
 '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'B' objects>, 
 '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'B' objects>, '__doc__': None, 
 'a.attr1': 'new'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of classes and python.

### `B.sub1.attr = 'some string'` doesn't work

`B` is the type `<class 'B'>`. There is no attribute `sub1` in type `B`.

#### However

I believe you expected a type `<class 'A'>`, you can do that by defining that attribute at the class level:

```py
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> class B:
...     sub1 = A()
...
>>> B.sub1
<__main__.A object at 0x7fa2e1d1c490>
```

*Weirdly, the same `sub1` is available as an instance attribute as well. That is a bug in python if you as me, open for discussion.*

```py
>>> b = B()
>>> b.sub1
<__main__.A object at 0x7fa2e1d1c490>
```

### `setattr(B, 'sub1.attr1', 'some string')` works

`setattr` will always work if the first parameter is an instance of a class. It forces the attribute to be available. It creates attributes in class objects.

### `B.sub1.attr1` doesn't work. While `getattr(B, 'sub1.attr1')` does

This is the weirdest of all, and I was not aware either. It boils down to the call to `setattr(B, 'sub1.attr1', 'some string')` just before. As discussed that forces the attribute.

What I believe is happening is you can't access that attribute via python syntax, since the attribute name actually contains a dot `sub1.attr1`. But you can pass a raw string as the attribute name to `getattr`, and thats why it works.

#### However

What you probably wanted to do in this scenario, is set the attribute to an instance of the class 'A'.

```py
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.attr1 = 'attr A'
...
>>> class B:
...     pass
...
>>> setattr(B, 'sub1', A())
>>> B.sub1.attr1
'attr A'
```

But at that point the attribute `sub1.attr1` does not exists!

```py
>>> getattr(B, 'sub1.attr1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'B' has no attribute 'sub1.attr1'
```

## Conclusion

You're doing some very weird stuff with the `getattr` and `setattr` built in functions. That is good if you're learning, but due note it takes knowledge of what is happening in the language to successfully use such functions.

With enough magic, an attribute name can actually have `.`s.